# Provider Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Color> above this MyApp Widget

Tags: flutter

I do not understand why the following code generates the error?
According to me the provider is an ancestor to MaterialApp and it should work? What am I missing?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        new Provider<Color>(create: (_) => Colors.amber)
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Provider.of<Color>(context),
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can create a `Provider` from an already existing Flutter class, in this case, `Color`. I would make another class that holds a `Color` property and create a `Provider` from that.

Comment: @BenjaminS. That is actually what I tried first, just changed the code for my question to make it more readable, so that is not the problem here!

Answer (score 0):

Provider initially in build method. You don't access to use provider value because provider inits context, but you tried to use provider.of(context) in the same place. If you use another state(view), you should use it.

Example code : https://gist.github.com/VB10/358dc944e5a86b58db2d898eaa1b5ea6

[image: provider sample]